# Is it expected that validation accuracy is a lot different for different seeds?

Tags: tensorflow

I train my CNN model with tensorflow, gpu, memory_growth enabled, op_determinism enabled and I select a random seed at the beginning of the script by using function: tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(some_number).

I see huge differences in validation accuracy for different seeds.
For example for seed some_number=8 I get an average accuracy of 90%, while for some_number=3 I get an average accuracy of 28%.

Is such a huge difference between different seeds expected or is something else going wrong?

Comment: Normally not. You will always have a bit of variance, but if you have to "get lucky" with the seed of training, it generally means either your network is too weak and not generalizing very well, or your dataset has a very high variance or is just very complicated.